# Should an automatically performed once-a-day operation for users be responded with an error code from the server for further attempts?

Tags: httprequest, http-status-code-403

I'm working on a project in which users automatically gain points if it's been more than 24h since their last login and a friendly message appears on the screen telling them that. If they log in again, nothing happens. But for me, as the dev of the project, I get a lot of scary red error messages in the browser logs showing me that a forbidden action has been tried, because when the backend detects that already made the transaction, it returns a 403, and this happens every time someone logs in or close and reopens the site.

I'm a bit confused whether this should really be the treatment for the case and wondering about how messed up error statistics of the site could get because of things like this, where nobody actually tried to perform a forbidden action, just the scheduled predictable behavior of the platform.

Should I change it to a 2xx status code?